# PHP checkbox values - insert into filename field on upload

Tags: php

Any insight on this would be appreciated.  Basically I have a file upload form that users can upload 5 files at a time.  On upload, I am adding 3 letters and a time stamp.  I want to insert check box values into the file name if they are checked:

```
 <form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file_up[]" type="file" class="file_up" size="16" maxlength=" " />
   CA<input name="state[]" type="checkbox" id="CA" value="CA" checked="checked" />
   NV<input name="state[]" type="checkbox" id="NV" value="NV" />
   UT<input name="state[]" type="checkbox" id="UT" value="UT" />
   AZ<input name="state[]" type="checkbox" id="AZ" value="AZ" />
<input name="file_up[]" type="file" class="file_up" size="16" maxlength=" " />
   CA<input name="state[]" type="checkbox" id="CA" value="CA" checked="checked" />
   NV<input name="state[]" type="checkbox" id="NV" value="NV" />
  UT<input name="state[]" type="checkbox" id="UT" value="UT" />
   AZ<input name="state[]" type="checkbox" id="AZ" value="AZ" />
```

There are 5 blocks like this, for each file field upload. The other 3 have state2[], etc.

In the file name section:

```
$updir . '/'.'337-'.implode("", $_POST['state']).$timestamp. $nume_f
```

How can I get just the 'state' values for each row?  So if CA is selected on the 1st row just add that CA to the 1st file, and not the others. It is not separating the check box rows.  I thought maybe making the 2nd group of check boxes state1, then the 3rd state2, etc.

The file loop is:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file_up'])) {
for($f=0; $f<count($_FILES['file_up']['name']); $f++)   {
$nume_f = $_FILES['file_up']['name'][$f];
```

Thanks for the responses on the 1st post, this is the 3rd EDIT.

Thoughts?  Thanks! -- Randy

```
EDIT:  The solution was to tie $f=0, $f=1, etc to a new variable:
 if($f == 0)$nume_g = ($_POST['state1']);
 if($f == 1)$nume_g = ($_POST['state2']); etc..
```

So each check box group is tied to the file name.  Thanks for all of the input, Randy

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `array(state)`? `state` in that context is an undefined constant.

Comment: And the `Array` you see is the string representation of the array `$_POST['state']`

Comment: Trying to get checkbox names "state[]" with an array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$_POST['state']
```

, write

```
implode("", $_POST['state']).
```

Implode merges array fields into string with first parameter as separator. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: On the upper PHP section or in the generate file name field?

Comment: @RandyS on generated file name. Also I don't know what variable is $value.

Comment: The $value would be the 'state' or CA, NV, etc.  I think my logic may be off here...

Comment: Like this?: $updir . '/'.'337-'.implode("", $_POST['state'].'-'.$timestamp;